# What is the meaning of _T("xyz")?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I wanted to understand the use of `_T("xyz")` in the code below:

```
#include<CString.h>
int main()
{
   uint32_t xyz = 15;
   LPCSTR Desc = "xyz value is : ";
   CString Value;
   Value = (LPCSTR)Desc + _T("xyz");
}
```

Will the above code display:

```
xyz value is : 15
```

or

```
xyz value is : xyz
```

How to display -

xyz value is : 15

Comment: Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx. Using `_T` in this case it totally wrong.

Comment: do you want to know what or why? for what, you just need to run the code, no?

Comment: ... and `Value = (LPCSTR)Desc + _T("xyz");` is totally wrong too.

Comment: I want to display xyz value is : 15..

Comment: I suggest you start reading your C++ text book.

Comment: Don't use `CString.h`, it's an ancient non-portable hack from times when C++ didn't have a usable string class.

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicate is helpful here. Voted for repopening

Comment: whats wrong with `std::cout << "xyz value is " << xyz;` ? Do you **have** to use `CString.h` ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky agree, maybe it was even a post like that that made OP think they need it for their case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
uint32_t xyz = 15;
LPCWSTR Desc = L"xyz value is : %d";
CString Value;
Value.Format(Desc, xyz);
```

Forget about the `_T` macro. What makes you think you should use it?

Or maybe you need this:

```
uint32_t xyz = 15;                // integer variable containing the number 15
CString stxyz;                    // CString variable
stxyz.Format(L"%d", xyz);          // stxyz contains "15" now

LPCWSTR Desc = L"xyz value is : ";  // Desc points to the string literal "15"

CString Value = Desc + stxyz;     // Value contains concatenation of Desc and stxyz
```

Comment: I have two string for which I need to concatenate

Comment: @CAAnusha OK, so you need to transform `xyz` into string first. BTW `"XYZ"` is a string literal, its content is in no way related to the identifier `xyz`.

Comment: I thought that is used to convert any non-string value to string

Comment: _I thought that is used to convert any non-string value to string_: absolutely not. You need to learn at least the basics of C++ to understand why my answers work.

Comment: I am using a user defined datatype basically a union instead of uint32_t ..
How should I store in string then?

Comment: I am getting below error
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2664 'void ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>::Format(const wchar_t *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [3]' to 'const wchar_t *'

Comment: Replace `LPCSTR` with `LPCWSTR` and replace `"xyz value is : "` with `L"xyz value is : "`.

Answer (score 1):

The `_T` macro is used to simplify transporting code for international uses.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx for more information.

Comment: ... at least that's what Microsoft would have developers believe.